# Does Scala have static imports like Java?

Tags: scala, static, import

Does Scala support static imports, like Java does?

Like, say:

```
import static java.util.Collections.singleton;
```

Can I also do the above in Scala? I'm getting a compile error when I try it -- something about a misplaced dot -- so presumably my syntax is incorrect?

Comment: I guess you didn't read/consult any Scala book in these 10 minutes - right?

Comment: No, no i didn't - that's why i asked the question here. I googled it, to no avail. I don't have a scala book here right now. I'm not sitting at home, kinda doing prod support.

Comment: I would say that it is not really a problem that the answer of a question can be found at some - more or less - obvious place...

Comment: This isn't a bad question. It is not analytically obvious what the analog to Java static imports should be, since java static imports import static members from a class and scala imports usually import instance members from an object (eg package object -- they are technically instance members).

Comment: Given that Googling "scala static import" redirects here, I'm glad the answer was also here, despite what the topic zealots decided.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just omit word `static` and it will work.

(feel free to omit also semicolon)

Comment: thanks! that was the ticket! will accept when it lets me.

Answer (score 41):

There are no statics in Scala, the nearest concept is the singleton object.
Like a Java static import, you can import all the members of a singleton object.

```
object MySingleton { .... }

object Main {
  import MySingleton._

}
```

You can also import all the static members of a Java class from Scala, just omit static.

```
import java.lang.Math._
```

Comment: You can also use this with your own Scala classes, as in: import org.MyClass._  where MyClass is your Scala object.  This lets you reference all of the methods and fields in it without prefixing them with the object name.